# Como colocar a porcentagem do peso de 2 campos Edittext via código sem usar xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho dois campos EdiText, nome e idade eu preciso que o campo nome fique com 70% da linha e a idade com 30%, no xml é fácil resolver isso, mas no código Java não estou conseguindo, alguém sabe como fazer? Agradeço desde já!

Estou usando este código para setar os parâmetros.

```
LayoutParams param5 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, X);
        nome_edit.setLayoutParams(param5);
```

Obs: Tentei deixar o primeiro parâmetro do LayoutParams em 0 e colocar um valor no lugar do X mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver! segue o código:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.7f); 0.7 é a porcentagem, coloquei 0.3 para a idade
        nome_edittext.setLayoutParams(lp1);
```